# Possible to have multiple admin profiles update a single Facebook page?

Tags: facebook

I have a page for a government entity that has multiple profiles that are administrator of the page.  Is it possible to setup the administrator accounts in such a way that any posts they make are automatically posted to the administered account?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In essence, no.
You can try something like [Hootsuite](http://hootsuite) whose CRM and delegation would probably help anyway.

Comment: Hootsuite would be great for this, i'm a big fan of it.